# pip install salt returns 'clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pip, salt

I'm on OSX. I'm installing Salt by following Salt's official guide [here](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough_macosx.html) and I've ran into a problem. Running 'sudo pip install salt' gives me the following error.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

I put the entire installation text in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danvayn/9d772bd646f2d99d83c1). I just want to install salt via pip. Any ideas?

**Attempted Solutions used from other overflow questions**

1. I've tried *export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments* and *export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments*
   in sudo bash
2. I've tried running sudo pip install salt with *ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"*
3. Updating xcode from 5.1 to 5.1.1, as I read this might be an xcode problem.

All of these return the same exact error. I don't know what to do. I've been hitting my head against this wall for about 2 hours with no resolve. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the environmental variable assignment after sudo:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" pip install gdal
```

Or, become root, then do the export:

```
sudo su - 
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" install gdal
pip install ...
```

It appears that the sudo command does not inherit the environmental variables, and they certainly aren't saved across multiple runs with sudo:

```
$ export  ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
$ sudo printenv | grep ARCHFLAGS
$
```