# Errors while installing matplotlib on OS X 10.8

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, clang, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to install matplotlib on my machine with OS X 10.8 and XCode 5.0.2. I get these weird errors of which I am not able to make sense. I used `pip install matplotlib` to install the package, but then it returns the following errors at the end.  I am clueless on what to do. Please help me proceed. I tried to install scipy through the same process and the same error stream prevails.

```
building 'rootfind' library

compiling C sources

C compiler: clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe



creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/optimize/Zeros

compile options: '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c'

clang: scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: Command "clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.o" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v3/xf03tznj5hn9mj7j_4jbkvw40000gn/T/pip_build_Siva/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v3/xf03tznj5hn9mj7j_4jbkvw40000gn/T/pip-u0HK_Y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v3/xf03tznj5hn9mj7j_4jbkvw40000gn/T/pip_build_Siva/scipy
```

After this I set the `ARCHFLAGS` variable to the following

```
export ARCHFLAGS='-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'
```

Although the installatoion proceeds a bit further, I get an error stream at a different point now.

```
running build_ext

building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/CXX

clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/ft2font.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZU81yE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common problem, the last macos updates make clang generate errors instead of warnings for unknown compiler options. As a temporary workaround you could set ARCHFLAGS environment variable, before running pip:

```
export ARCHFLAGS='-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'
```

Comment: Though it proceeds a bit further, I still get the same error after I set the flags as you have said. I have updated the question with the new errors.

Comment: As suggested by @psl I set the `ARCHFLAGS` variable using the following and it worked.

`sudo ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" pip install matplotlib`

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/23022901/1468760][1]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Canopy as a python environment on OS X since it is usually harder to install python packages on a Mac.

You can get it here : https://www.enthought.com/downloads/.

MatPlotLib is installed by default, and many more packages are easier to install after installing Canopy.

Comment: I am trying to install matplotlib for another package ROS - Robotic Operating System. Since matplotlib is a dependency for one of its packages. In case I install Canopy, would it serve for that ?